# Python - Googletrans for multiple txt files in loop

Tags: python, google-translate, googletrans

I'm seeking to run googletrans to translate a series of 300 .txt files in a single folder. I'm struggling to construct a loop that will allow me to run a translation of each file and write the output in new .txt files. Googletrans has a limit on bulk translations, so I'm happy to limit the iterations to 50 files at a time.

Here's the code for translating a single file. It prints the original txt file, then the translated file, and finally outputs the file into a new txt file.

```
from googletrans import Translator

f = open('Translation Project\page_323.txt', 'r')

if f.mode == 'r':
    contents = f.read()
    print(contents)

translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate(contents, dest='en')
print(result.text)

with open('Translation Project\trans_page_323.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(result.text)
```

Any thoughts? New to Python and still wrapping my head around loops.

Comment: This looks great, but may be a question for [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/). What question are you asking? Are you asking how to make this into a loop, or are you asking if this would work?

Comment: Thanks for the assistance and advice. I'm asking how to make this into a loop.

Comment: Are the file names formatted as `trans_page_1.txt` or `trans_page_001.txt`? Also, what is the max page number?

Comment: Also, it may help to edit the question to make that a bit more clear :-)

Comment: If my answer helped, would you mind upvoting it and marking it as the solution? That would help out a ton! Thank you!

Comment: Happy to do so - working on earning reputation to upvote! Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that there are 999 pages, the files are formatted as `trans_page_1.txt` rather than `trans_page_001.txt`, and that the first page is page 1, not page 0:

```py
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

for page_number in range(1, 999):

    f = open(f'Translation Project\page_{page_number}.txt', 'r')

    if f.mode == 'r':
        contents = f.read()
        print(contents)


    result = translator.translate(contents, dest='en')
    print(result.text)

    with open(f'Translation Project\trans_page_{page_number}.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.write(result.text)
```

This doesn't limit the files translated, but you can do this by changing the maximum page to 50 or by doing some other code shenanigans.

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much for the assistance, and patience working through my lack of clarity.